# smack api giving error to login gtalk

Tags: xmpp, google-talk

I used all the api's related to smack so that i could login and use the gtalk in my and app. All the api's (smack 3.22, asmack, qsmack) give me same error. Error is coppied from logcat and pasted below. Please help me i am almost frustated now :(

```
     XMPPConnection xmppConnection;
            String host = "talk.google.com";
            int port = 6222; 
            String service = "gmail.com";
            String username = "test1";
            String password = "password";

            try {
                xmppConnection = new XMPPConnection(new ConnectionConfiguration(host,
                        port, service));
                xmppConnection.connect();
                xmppConnection.login(username, password);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

No response from the server.:

```
 at    org.jivesoftware.smack.NonSASLAuthentication.authenticate(NonSASLAuthentication.java:74)
   at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:404)
   at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:349)
   at com.android.xmppproject.XmppManager.performLogin(XmppManager.java:56)
   at com.android.xmppproject.XMPPProjectActivity.onCreate(XMPPProjectActivity.java:29)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have provided incorrect GTalk port.
Please try **port = 5222**